# Azure data lake handling sensitive data

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-information-protection

Does Azure storage (Blob/Data lake Gen) supports handling sensitive data? I see Azure Information Protection is one way to handle sensitive data in azure but I'm not able to find if it's supported with ADLS. If it is not supported how does one restricts user to view files with sensitive data in it?

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 protects your data throughout its life cycle. For data in transit, Data Lake Storage Gen1 uses the industry-standard Transport Layer Security (TLS 1.2) protocol to secure data over the network.

**Encryption** in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1 helps you protect your data, implement enterprise security policies, and meet regulatory compliance requirements.

Data Lake Storage Gen1 supports encryption of data both at **rest** and in **transit**. For data at rest, Data Lake Storage Gen1 supports "on by default," transparent encryption.

[image]

Data Lake Storage Gen1 also provides encryption for data that is stored in the account. You can chose to have your data encrypted or opt for no encryption. If you opt in for encryption, data stored in Data Lake Storage Gen1 is encrypted prior to storing on persistent media. In such a case, Data Lake Storage Gen1 automatically encrypts data prior to persisting and decrypts data prior to retrieval, so it is completely transparent to the client accessing the data. There is no code change required on the client side to encrypt/decrypt data.

**Reference:** [Encryption of data in Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-encryption)

Comment: I know about encryption..My concern is regarding sensitive data stored in data lake such as credit card numbers and pins or any other sensitive data  in a file that should be accessed by only some users and not all. How do you mask those records in data lake files?

Comment: FYI,  Azure Data Lake has limited data security (no row-level, column-level, dynamic data masking, etc) and the difficulty in accessing it compared to accessing a relational database. Azure SQL Database, Azure SQL Managed Instance, and Azure Synapse Analytics support dynamic data masking. Dynamic data masking limits sensitive data exposure by masking it to non-privileged users.